# Asking question as to how to create a php inside a script?

Tags: javascript, php

How do you put a javascript inside a php?
here is my code to be put inside.
or could this be translated to a PHP code?

I am new to web development and I don't know how to do it.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function(){
            var favorite = [];
            var total = 0;
            var i;
            $.each($("input[name='remember']:checked"), function(){            
                favorite.push($(this).val());
            });

            for (i = 0; i < favorite.length; i++) {
                total += parseInt(favorite[i]);
            }

                alert(total);

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There is no use of JS in server-side. Why do you want that?

Comment: I just want to get the value I've got from the check boxes then compare the value I got to a certain value to know what it is equivalent to. then put the equivalent value to the database table

Comment: Make an API call from JS instead?

Answer (score 0):

For this use ajax and save the data in the database. Follow this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        var favorite = [];
        var total = 0;
        var i;
        $.each($("input[name='remember']:checked"), function(){            
            favorite.push($(this).val());
        });

        for (i = 0; i < favorite.length; i++) {
            total += parseInt(favorite[i]);
        }

         saveData(total);

    });

    function saveData(total) {
       var URL = 'test.php';
          $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: {data : total}, // retrieve your data in test.php using "data" key from $_POST variable
            success: (response) => {
            // console.log(response);
            }
          });
     }

});
</script>
```

Comment: can this be made using PHP scripts?

Comment: No, You certainly can not bind a variable in which client-side changes will reflect the server-side. So you need to send the changes to the server from the client-side and for that, you need to send HTTP request. This is how web architecture works. Why do you face any problem doing like this?